# C++: How to create a constant at compile time?

Tags: c++, hash

I want to create a constant at compile time. This is what I mean:

```
template <int M = 31>
int fast_hash(int prev_hash, int c1, int c3)
{
    enum {m3 = m*m*m;}
    return m * prev_hash - m3 * c1 + c3;
}
```

In the above example, I could calculate m3 = m*m*m every time the function is called, but I think it would be cooler if this is done just once and during compile time. How can I do this?

Comment: I think m3 will be a constant in this case. After constant propagation the compiler would evaluate m3 as a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would best be done with **C++11**'s `constexpr`, but in **C++03** you can still do it with a metafunction:

```
template< int M >
struct some_calculation
{
    static const int value = M * M * M;
};
```

It's certainly *cooler*, but I think you are worrying about it too much and too early.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil after all.

Comment: Besides the comment on premature optimization, this does not solve anything that was not already solved in the original piece of code, while this yields a constant expression in C++, so does `enum { m3 = m*m*m };` (i.e. you can only provide values to enums with constant expressions resolved at compile time)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are misunderstanding what the code you provide does in C++:

```
template <int M = 31>
int fast_hash(int prev_hash, int c1, int c3)
{
    enum {m3 = m*m*m;}
    return m * prev_hash - m3 * c1 + c3;
}
```

In the original code, `m3` is already a compile time constant (constant expression). The compiler will calculate it and substitute the uses by the value. Note that you can only set the value of an enumerator from a constant expression (calculated at compile time).

As a matter of fact, this is a premature optimization. In most cases you don't even need to define the enumeration, as given a compile time constant `M` (template argument), all compilers will substitute `M*M*M` with the proper value. That is trivial to implement for the compiler, and no production grade compiler would fail to do it.